# Building a Table From perl Hash with colspan

Tags: perl

I have a hash similar to

```
 $hash{$kayA}{$keyB}{val=>$value};
```

I need to out put this into a html table the TD containg $keyA needs a rowspan based on the number of keys at $keyB

so the output might look like

```
<html>
<body>
<table border='1'>
  <tr><th colspan='2' >Col A</th><th>Col B</th><th>Value</th></tr>
  <tr>
  <td rowspan='2'><input name='myButton' type= "radio" id ="R1"></td>
  <td rowspan='2'> this is first kay</td>
  <td> this is second key 1</td><td>Value 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>this is second key 2</td><td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

this is as far as my perl script has got i'm struging with how to get the tr in the correct place

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$hash{$kayA}{$keyB}{val=>$value};
my $TabPrt = "<table><tr><th>Col A></th><th>Col B</th><th>Value</th></tr>";
for my $keyA (sort keys %hash)
  {
   my $Row = scaler keys %{$hash}{kayA};
   $Row = "rowspan='$Row'";

   $TabPrt = $TabPrt. "<tr>  <td><input name='myButton' type= "radio" id ="R1"></td><td $Row></td>";
   for my $keyB (sort keys %{$hash}{$keyA}
    {
      my $val = hash{$kayA}{$keyB}{val};
      $TabPrt = $TabPrt . " <td>$keyB</td><td>$val</td>"
    }
  }

 $TabPrt = $TabPrt . "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: `use strict;` and `use warnings;` will show you that "scaler" is a typo, and not the intended "scalar".

Comment: Thanx Typo aside how dose the logic work with where to put <tr> &</tr>?

Comment: it is extremely annoying to write such long deep template constructions in Perl. Either program your own templating system, use custom DSL or quit writing complex reports and use more object-oriented approach. TMTOWTDI never assumed that hard programmatic porn is the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand neither your data structure, nor your code.

This `$hash{$kayA}{$keyB}{val=>$value};` compiles, but has no real meaning in Perl.

Also, this line is faulty:

```
$TabPrt = $TabPrt. "<tr>  <td><input name='myButton' type= "radio" id ="R1"></td><td $Row></td>";
```

It does not compile, as the string `"<tr>  <td><input name='myButton' type= "` terminates just before `radio`. I think you meant

```
$TabPrt .= q(<tr><td><input name="myButton" type="radio" id ="R1"></td><td>$Row</td>);
```

Use the `q()` or `qq()` (interpolates) quote operators, to quote strings that contain `'` or `"` characters.

I assume you want your table to be rendered like

```
+----------------------------------+------------------------+---------+
| Col A                            | Col B                  | Value   |
+==========+=======================+========================+=========+
| o Button | this is the first key | this is the second key | Value 1 |
|          |                       +------------------------+---------+
|          |                       | this is the second key | Value 2 |
+----------+-----------------------+------------------------+---------+
```

Now let's assume that your hash looks like

```
my %hash = (
    key1 => { A => "val1", B => "val2" },
    key2 => { C => "val1", D => "val2" },
);
```

we can then iterate over this hash and construct the HTML:

```
sub make_table_corpus {
    my ($hash) = @_;
    my $html = "";
    for my $key (sort keys %$hash) {
        my $sub_hash = $hash->{$key};
        # first: how many rows will this key span?
        my $rowspan = keys %$sub_hash;
        # then: prepare all the secondary keys. Will return HTML fragments:
        my @secondary = prep_secondary_keys($sub_hash);
        $html .= html("tr", {},
            html("td", {rowspan => $rowspan}, " o Button "),
            html("td", {rowspan => $rowspan}, $key),
            # put the first secondary key here
            shift @secondary,
        );
        # append the other secondary keys:
        $html .= html("tr", {}, $_) for @secondary;
    }
    return $html;
}

# emits html fragments of key-value pairs, as <td> cells.
sub prep_secondary_keys {
    my ($hash) = @_;
    map { html("td", {}, $_) . html("td", {}, $hash->{$_}) }
        sort keys %$hash;
}

# creates a html fragment
sub html {
    my ($name, $attr, @childs) = @_;
    my $attrstring = "";
    while (my ($attname, $value) = each %$attr) {
        $value =~ s/"/&quot;/g;
        $attrstring .= qq( $attname="$value");
    }
    return join "", qq(<$name$attrstring>), @childs, qq(</$name>);
}
```

Then:

```
print make_table_corpus(\%hash);
```

With the above hash this would produce output like

```
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2"> o Button </td>
  <td rowspan="2">key1</td>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>val1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>B</td>
  <td>val2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2"> o Button </td>
  <td rowspan="2">key2</td>
  <td>C</td>
  <td>val1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>D</td>
  <td>val2</td>
</tr>
```

(without the intendation, of course)

#### What I did different

1. I didn't do syntax errors (`use strict; use warnings` to get warned about errors and mistakes)
2. The secondary keys are processed by an external subroutine. That way, we can simply take the first HTML fragment and put it into the first row easily.
3. I wrote the `html` sub to avoid excessive quoting issues in my source code. While this does not substitute a templating system, it makes life a bit easier, and introduces a single point of failure for mistakes, which makes problems easier to fix.

Extending the solution to print out the table headers, and producing a valid HTML table is a trivial step from here.